# How to get the potential and the gradient of this function?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

How to calculate the potential $P_3:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the $\nabla P_3=f_3$ of the function $f_3:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ with

$\large f_3(x,y,z)=(2xe^{x^2y^2z^2}+y,2ye^{x^2y^2z^2}+z,2ze^{x^2y^2z^2}+x)$?

Comment: Do you know what $\nabla $ is?

Comment: @Chilango I can only find information on $\nabla$ related to physics.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe a potential _exists_ for this particular vector field...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think I understand now. Is it correct that $P$ exists if and only if the curl is 0? If so, I have reason to believe $f_3(x,y,z)$ does not have a $P$.

Comment: @Arthur: On a simply-connected set (such as all of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$, as is the case here), a vector field $f$ has a potential if and only if the curl of $f$ is zero. On a set that is not simply-connected, a vector field _can_ have vanishing curl at every point yet still not have a potential. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks.